# Delphi Rio 10.3 - Google Play Nível da API 28

Tags: delphi-10, google-play

Estou tentando publicar uma APP no Google Play e o Google Play esta me retornando a seguinte mensagem abaixo:

"No momento o nível desejado da API do seu app é 26. No entanto, esse nível precisa ser de pelo menos 28 para que o app use as APIs mais recentes, que contam com otimizações de segurança e desempenho. Altere o nível desejado da API do seu app para pelo menos 28. Saiba como fazer isso."

Estou usando o Delphi Rio 10.3 com Windows 7, tentei mudar o SDK para pegar a última versão mas não funciona. Sempre que tento carregar a APP no Google Play vem essa mensagem.

A configuração do meu SDK está conforme as imagens abaixo:

[image: SDK]

[image: SDK]
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver?

Answer (score -1):

Rode o bat no seu PC em C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat

[image: SDK Manager: Parte 1]
[image: SDK Manager: Parte 2]
Desmarque tudo apertando em Deselect ALL onde selecionei na foto em roxo depois e só marcar todas as caixas que selecionei em verde agora e só apertar em Install Packages.

no seu delphi é só alterar onde marquei em verde de android-26 para android-28 deixando igual a sua foto abaixo.

[image: sua foto]
OBS: caso ainda continue com o erro deixe tudo igual a baixo.

[image: Alternativa]